# Счетные обороты с дробными и смешанными числами при наличии определения

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

Как выбрать в этом случае число   существительного?

1) Нет определения

Длина 0,5 м, 2,5 м, 16,5 м: ноль целых  пять десятых (долей) метра, две целых  пять десятых метра, **шестнадцать целых  пять десятых метра**.

Всё по грамматическим правилам: числитель дроби управляет пропущенным словом "долей", а существительное всегда имеет форму Р.п. ед.ч., обозначая часть целого.

2) Есть определение

Площадь 0,5 м2, 2,5 м2, 16,5 м2: ноль целых  пять десятых квадратного метра, две целых  пять десятых квадратного метра, шестнадцать целых  пять десятых квадратного метра.

Но мы  так не говорим, мы говорим: **площадь комнаты шестнадцать  и пять десятых квадратных метров.**  Мы просто называем единицу измерения в форме Р.п. мн.ч, как бы отбрасывая доли, и чем больше целое число, тем это вероятнее. И это происходит **именно при наличии определения.**

Почему мы так говорим? А как же правила? Или мы не должны так говорить? Может быть, это разговорная форма?

Но ведь в общем виде **правила сочетаемости** слов существуют, зависят от различных **факторов** и отражаются на письме. Кстати, в Грамматике дробные числа не принадлежат к числительным, а рассматриваются как особые сочетания с количественным значением.

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm

8. Правильными являются конструкции 35,5 процента (не ...процентов), 12,6 километра (не ...километров), т.е. при смешанном числе существительным управляет дробь, а не целое число.  Также: 45,0 (сорок пять и ноль десятых) секунды, 67/8 (шесть и семь восьмых) метра и т.п.

Но здесь **нет определений.**

А вот у Грамоты.ру есть определение и ответ на вопрос, только нет ссылок на правила.

Вопрос № 287901
Скажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти подробное правило о согласовании дробных числительных с прилагательным и существительным (например: 0,68 сотых квадратных метров? квадратного метра?)?
Ответ. При смешанном числе существительным управляет дробь, а не целое число. Правильно: **0,68 квадратного метра.**

Comment: У Грамоты есть еще один ответ: 4,67 календарного дня. Но тут нужно заметить, что квадратный метр и календарный день — единицы измерения. А вот "4,67 зеленого яблока" режет слух еще сильнее. Но правило-то одно для всех! Определение управляется существительным. Мне кажется, другого правила нет. Вывод, который я делаю для себя: просто избегать такой "неблагозвучности".

Comment: 1) Я вижу правило у Розенталя, но там нет определения, а других правил нет. Я не знаю, откуда Грамота.ру их берет, они не дают ссылок. Это что, законодательный орган, может дополнять и корректировать официальные правила? 2) А как избегать? "Квадратные метры" в своих квартирах все считают. Я же не скажу: шестнадцать с половиной квадратного метра, а "шестнадцать и пять десятых квадратного метра" я должна почему-то говорить. 3) Пожалуйста,  используйте поле ответа, а не комментария. А то получится очередной вопрос без ответа.

Comment: 1) А в чем Грамота "корректирует официальные правила"?

Comment: Официальными правилами  я считаю Правила 1956 года, подробно изложенные у Розенталя, и ПАС, в которые внесены некоторые поправки. У Розенталя я не нашла варианта с определением, а у Грамоты.ру нет ссылок на источник информации.  Значит, это собственная трактовка образовательного сайта? А Вы не могли бы ответить на вопрос, мне очень интересно Ваше мнение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Розенталь в книге "Трудные вопросы грамматики и правописания" поясняет насчёт "половины".

> Существительное при смешанном числе управляется дробью: 2 3/5 (два и
>   три пятых) метра; 8,1 (восемь и одна десятая) секунды и т. п. Поэтому
>   45,5 процента; 41,1 процента; 41,0 (сорок один и ноль десятых)
>   процента. В зависимости от наличия десятичной или простой дроби
>   возможны два варианта; так, в спортивных выражениях мы встречаем: 5,5
>   (пять и пять десятых) очка, но 5 1/2 (пять с половиной) очков. Мы
>   обычно читаем сорок пять с половиной процентов, а не сорок пять и одна
>   вторая процента. Наблюдая выражения 2 1/2, 3 1/2, 4 1/2 (два с
>   половиной и т. д.) очка и 5 1/2 (пять с половиной) очков, мы видим,
>   что при наличии в числовом сочетании слов с половиной существительное
>   управляется целым числом, а в остальных случаях — дробью.

Как уже было сказано ранее, определение управляется существительным по общим правилам. Следует признать, что около половины обнаруженных в солидных изданиях случаев употребления выражений "вылетевших птенца", "золотых рубля" и "канадских доллара" с десятичными дробями ошибочны (я смотрел только эти выражения).

Comment: Да, спасибо, с "половиной" ясно, но вот определения перед существительным в этих примерах нет. Где бы это найти? Но всё-таки уже хорошо, что правило дает варианты чтения.

Answer (score 2):

Розенталь пишет:

> 8. Правильными являются конструкции 35,5 процента (не ...процентов), 12,6 километра (не ...километров), т.е. при смешанном числе существительным управляет дробь, а не целое число. Также: 45,0 (сорок пять и ноль десятых) секунды, 67/8 (шесть и семь восьмых) метра и т.п. ([§166. Сочетания числительных с существительными](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm))

Однако Розенталь ничего не говорит об определении, которое может стоять при существительном. Поэтому возникает вопрос: "3,33 яблока" — корректно, но корректно ли "3,33 зеленого яблока"? Ответ, по-моему, таков. По общему правилу существительное управляет определением. Единственное известное мне исключение: рассогласование существительного и определения, стоящих после числительных полтора, два, три четыре (три зеленых  яблока). Раз нигде не сказано, что счетные обороты с дробной частью являются исключением, то следуем общему правилу:  3,33 зеленого яблока. Звучит странно для вашего уха? Для моего тоже. Я старюсь избегать таких конструкций.

Comment: Рассогласование - это то, что в речи стараются избегать. Ведь недаром существуют правила сочетаемости по числу для подлежащего и сказуемого, для подлежащего и ряда определений. Поэтому нельзя выводить правило для одной конструкции из каких-то общих правил, всё индивидуально. Я думаю, что это скорее грамматическая задача, возможно там надо искать ответ.